# Can a you restrict a Sharepoint user from editing a list item after adding it via a workflow?

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

We currently have a number of workflows in our organization that require users to add an item to a list via a form, but then not be able to edit that item unless given special permission to do so.

For example a user submits a leave of absence request and it is routed to their manager. The 1st level manager might approve this request and the workflow continues. While the request is in the managers hands it cannot be modified by the original submitter, however if the manager rejects it or requires revision the original submitter should then be able to edit.

Is this possible? The best strategy we could come up with for this is multiple Lists to handle the different levels of security required for this. Are there better ways of doing this?

SharePoint seems to have a very open concept of security within an SP site and maybe were just trying to fit a square peg in a round hole.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about Remove permission for that user/for all user using workflow itself?

http://spcycle.blogspot.jp/2012/01/how-to-create-workflow-to-change-item.html

http://shareapointkiran.blogspot.jp/2012/06/addremove-permissions-using-sharepoint.html

And then give it back when manager approves/rejects

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it with a quick and dirty solution.

In our case this quick and dirty solution might be even easier.
You could add a hidden field that has an default value of for example 0.
Then you add a (formating) rule to one of the fields that should be deactived.
The rule should deactivate the field if the value of the hidden field is not 0.
This rule can be copied to every field that should be deactivated too.

Now add a set field action to your workflow that set the value of the hidden field to something else than 0, for example 1.

To make a hidden field you can define formating rule with a condition that is always true.

Now if someone creates a form the workflow will set the value of your hidden field to 1. The rule of the fields that should be deactived will now deactivate the fields.

[Hide the field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MD38.png)

[Deactivate the field rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nASvv.png)